# TemplateSyntaxError at Posts, First Django Project

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to make my first Django project. I'm making the first post and in the the tutorial, it goes like this in HTML:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> This is our list of post</h1>
    {% for post in post_objects &}
        {{ post }}
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Now that I'm trying to run the server and check the page so I can see the 'This is our list of post', there is an error.

```
Error during template rendering
In template C:\Users\Invoker\Dev\trydjango\src\posts\templates\posts\index.html, error at line 10

Invalid block tag on line 10: 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
1   <!DOCTYPE html>
2   <html>
3   <head>
4       <title></title>
5   </head>
6   <body>
7       <h1> This is our list of post</h1>
8       {% for post in post_objects &}
9           {{ post }}
10      {% endfor %}
11  </body>
12  </html>
```

What should I do?

Comment: `{% for post in post_objects &}` notice that you end with `&}` it should be `%}` instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao Sadra!
I see, the error message is not helping at all. But I think it's just a typo!

```
{% for post in post_objects &}
```

At the end of the `for` block there's a `&` when there should be a `%`.

Comment: "_But I think it's just a typo_", since it is just a typo this answer should also be "just a comment". One should refrain from answering questions caused by typographical errors. You should simply point out the typo in a comment and optionally flag / vote to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

[Template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/zh-hans/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters) syntax: `{% load %}`.

You need to make the following changes.

```
{% for post in post_objects %}
```